# Show that $ \{ (\phi \wedge \psi) \rightarrow \theta \} \vdash \phi \rightarrow(\psi \rightarrow \theta)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How to show that $ \{ (\phi \wedge \psi) \rightarrow \theta \} \vdash \phi \rightarrow(\psi \rightarrow \theta)$?

I tried to do it using deduction theorem and got $\vdash((\phi \wedge \psi) \rightarrow \theta) \rightarrow  (\phi \rightarrow(\psi \rightarrow \theta))$. 
After that rewrote it like $\vdash(\neg(\phi \rightarrow \neg \psi) \rightarrow \theta) \rightarrow  (\phi \rightarrow(\psi \rightarrow \theta))$, but now I dont have no idea what to do next...

Comment: What proof system are you using?  There are *dozens* of different proof systems!

Comment: Also, is that last $\phi$ supposed to be a $\theta$? ... and I would put parentheses around the conjunction to be clear ...

Comment: Also, note that you can only apply the Deduction Theorem on what you have already proven. You are trying to apply it to what needs to be proven ...

Comment: Can you prove $\{((\phi\land\psi)\to\theta),\phi,\psi\}\vdash\theta$ ? If so, then the deduction theorem becomes a good idea.

Comment: See [Exportation (logic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_%28logic%29#Proof) for the proof of the equivalence.

Comment: @AndreasBlass You use reverse deduction theorem to get $\{((\phi \wedge \psi)\rightarrow \theta), \phi, \psi\} \vdash \theta$??

Comment: I don't recall ever having heard the phrase "reverse deduction theorem" but it seems a reasonable description of the modus ponens rule of inference. If that's what you mean, then you also need to get from $\{\phi,\psi\}$ to $\phi\land\psi$, and the details of that will depend on the particular proof system you're using.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but I need to prove it using Modus Ponens... Do you have any idea how to do it???

Comment: See first comment above: "What proof system are you using? "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

We can use the following [axiom system for propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems#Intuitionistic_and_intermediate_logics), with *modus ponens* as the only rule of inference.

As usual, Ax.1 and Ax.2 are used to prove the *Deduction Theorem*.

1) $(ϕ∧ψ)→θ$ --- premise

2) $ϕ$ --- assumption [a]

3) $ψ$ --- assumption [b]

4) $\vdash ϕ \to (ψ \to (ϕ∧ψ))$ --- axiom

5) $(ϕ∧ψ)$ --- from 2) and 3) and 4) by *modus ponens* twice

6) $θ$ --- from 5) and 1) by *modus ponens*

7) $(ψ \to θ)$ --- from 3) and 6) by *Deduction Th*, discharging temporary assumption [b]

> 8) $ϕ \to (ψ \to θ)$ --- from 2) and 7) by *Deduction Th*, discharging temporary assumption [a].